# SQL Server : procedure or function to loop over each (PARTITION BY ...) element

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I am learning SQL syntax on practical examples. I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders_tmp_test]
(
    department_id VARCHAR(4),
    rank_pr_co INT,
    starting_date DATE, 
    end_date DATE
)
 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders_tmp_test]
    SELECT '1001', 1, '2019/04/01', '2020/02/01'
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT '1001', 2, '2020/01/31', '2020/04/30'
    UNION ALL     
    SELECT '1001', 3, '2020/03/01', '2020/03/01'
    UNION ALL     
    SELECT '1001', 4, '2020/03/31', '2020/05/31'
    UNION ALL     
    SELECT '1002', 1, '2019/03/01', '2020/02/01'
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT '1002', 2, '2020/01/01', '2020/04/01'
```

Each department has several projects. Projects are executed in sequence provided by "rank_pr_co". When current project is not ended yet, but another project already started for the given department it is called conflict. I want to modify "starting_date" and "end_date" of projects which will resolve all conflicts. Lengths of projects are fixed. For projects where "starting_date"="end_date" I want to leave them as it is. In this case, I want to resolve conflicts between one previous and one next projects.

At the end I want to have the following table:

```
'1001', 1, '2019/04/01', '2020/02/01'
'1001', 2, '2020/02/01', '2020/05/01'
'1001', 3, '2020/03/01', '2020/03/01'
'1001', 4, '2020/05/01', '2020/07/01'
'1002', 1, '2019/03/01', '2020/02/01'
'1002', 2, '2020/02/01', '2020/05/01'
```

I tried to create scalar function and cast it over (partition by ...) elements, but it does not work and returns the error:

> Msg 4113, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> The function 'dbo.ideal_schema' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause.

Anybody have any idea how to derive the final table?

Comment: I don't see how your sample data resolves the conflicts.

Comment: User defined functions can't have windowing. Only specific aggregate and analytical T-SQL functions can.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the fast response. In new table the ('1001',2) is starting when previous project ('1001',1) is ended. That is resolving the conflicting timelines of those projects.

Comment: @baraban55 . . . But it ends after the next project.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Exactly! That is the main difficulty. ('1001', 3) is the special one. It starts and ends the same date (immediately done). That is why I resolve conflict between  ('1001', 2) and ('1001', 4) instead and leave ('1001', 3) as it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want no overlapping dates within a project and the end date is non-inclusive, then just use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(end_date, 1, end_date) over (partition by project_id order by start_date) as imputed_end_date
from Orders_tmp_test t;
```

Note:  This does **not** use the ordering column on purpose.  You would have to have a lot more explanation about what to do in edge cases where the dates and the specified ordering have nothing to do with each other.

Note:  If you actually want to `update` the table, this can easily be incorporated into an `update` statement.  I see no reason to write a user-defined function for this.  You *might* want a view, if you want this information available when you query the table.

Comment: Seems like "lead" function might be the right direction. However, it does not resolve some of the issues. Both "starting_date" and "end_date" should be changed. Also if "starting_date"="end_date", then it should not changed at all.